# AIML pattern with exact count of word

Tags: pattern-matching, artificial-intelligence, aiml

I have following **`test.aiml.csv`** file :-

```
0,GIVE ^ * of ^ INSTANCE ^ *,*,*,
<test service="pannous"><star index = "2"/> GIVE THE DETAILS OF <star index = "5"/></test>,test.aiml
```

I have following **`test.aiml`** file :-

```
<category><pattern>GIVE ^ * of ^ INSTANCE ^ *</pattern>
<template><test service="pannous">SEARCH BPM details <star index = "2"/> of  <star index = "5"/></test></template>
</category>
```

So when i ask bot to like this :-

**GIVE us the state of the xyz INSTANCE 70599** the values accured by the stars-2 is `us the state` and by star-5 is `70599`.

But my expectation was **star-2:- state**
How can i get only the last word just before the **of**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you use the optional wildcards (^ etc) the star indexes are relative to the actual number of wild cards in use. So you may need to srai to another pattern GIVE * OF * to parse out the actual text that was used.